# Google Directions API, reduce XML output size

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions, google-directions-api, driving-directions

I'm using the Google Directions API specified here
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

it's working good, but the XML returned is a bit large, I don't need all the data they give.

the questions is, can I ask for a specific set of results?!
in my case, I want in "step" only "start_location" and "html_instructions".

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a filter on resultset like you have mentioned above. If `XML`'s size is too large , you can use `JSON` instead. `Google` recommends to use `JSON` format:

> We recommend that you use json as the preferred output flag unless
>   your service requires xml for some reason. Processing XML trees
>   requires some care, so that you reference proper nodes and elements.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#XML

Comment: a bit large, actually I'm talking about a 30 KB file :D
JSON in such a case is larger than XML

Comment: It can be large than `XML`, if there are extra 'new lines','space',etc.. symbols. If eliminate that symbols it is far more lightweight. Also JSON object holds less memory than XML document. So it is always better to work with JSON in javascript, than with XML.